# HashMap Inside Hashmap printing involving strings?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I need to be able to get a value from a HashMap that is inside another HashMap. I'm not really that familiar with HashMaps so I can't really figure this out myself.
Code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class testfile2 {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> rooms = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

        HashMap<String,String> roomA = new HashMap<String,String>();
        roomA.put("desc1","You are in a dark room made out of wood. Some light shines through a window to the South.From this light you can make out a door to the East");
        roomA.put("desc2", "You are in a dark room made out of wood. Some light shines through a broken window to the South.From this light you can make out a door to the East. There is a tunnel leading outwards from the window.");
        rooms.put("roomA", roomA);

        HashMap<String, String> roomB = new HashMap<String, String>();
        roomB.put("desc1", "You are in a dark wooden room. There is nothing here but a doorway leading to the West.");
        roomB.put("desc2", "You are in a dark wooden room. There is a doorway that leads to the West. There is also an axe you can take on the ground.");
        rooms.put("roomB", roomB);

        HashMap<String, String> roomC = new HashMap<String, String>();
        roomC.put("desc1", "You are in a completely white rectangular room. There is a rectangular hole in the wall to the North.");
        rooms.put("roomC", roomC);

        System.out.print(rooms.get("roomA"));

    }
}
```

I need to be able to call "desc1" from the string "roomA" that is in the HashMap rooms.

To further clarify: System.out.print(rooms.get("roomA".get("desc1"));
Something like the print statement up above is what I need. I know I can't use the String "roomA" with the .get but if there is any way I can do this, I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

`rooms.get("roomA").get("desc1")` Is the short answer. Since you're new to HashMaps, let's clarify that a bit.

`rooms` is a `HashMap` that maps a string to `HashMap<String, String>`. So every `.get(...)` you call on rooms has a return type of `HashMap<String, String>`. Calling `.get(...)` on anything of `HashMap<String, String>` returns a value of type `String`, which is what you're going for.

Thus

```
rooms.get("roomA")
```

returns a `HashMap<String,String>`, and

```
rooms.get("roomA").get("desc1")
```

returns the String.

Another way of thinking about it is splitting it into two statements:

```
HashMap<String, String> myRoom = rooms.get("roomA");
String desc = myRoom.get("desc1");
```

Which can then easily be squished down to `rooms.get("roomA").get("desc1")`.

Answer (score 0):

`rooms.get("roomA").get("desc1")` should work.

Of course it would be better to check for existence, to avoid potential `NullPointerException` :

```
if (rooms.get("roomA") != null) {
    System.out.println(rooms.get("roomA").get("desc1"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I'll also try to avoid the NullPointerException.